# Editing PKDrawing in PencilKit

Tags: ios13, ipados, apple-pencil, pencilkit

When using PencilKit in iOS 13/iPadOS, how do you change the content in PKDrawing? For example, can I go through all the lines and change the color or width of the lines? Or for selected lines (via lasso)? Or add a straight line in our own code?

Comment: tip: If you are using the PKToolSet you can use the select tool to select strokes. With them selected, chose a new color in the tool bar and it will change those strokes to that color

Comment: …but doing in programmatically?

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it programmatically - But there might be some hints here: https://github.com/w0lfschild/macOS_headers/blob/master/macOS/PrivateFrameworks/PencilKit/20/PKStrokeSelection.h

Answer (score 3):

PKDrawing is listed as an Opaque data object. See this [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) for an explanation of opaque data object. Unfortunately strokes are not exposed to us.  Our only 2 options currently can be found in the docs under [Modifying the Drawing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkdrawing?language=objc). Basically we can only apply a transform or append drawings in the current api.  In [Apple's Demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit), they show how to implement undo using the append method.  If you download the demo, see `func setNewDrawingUndoable(_ newDrawing: PKDrawing)` to see how you can implement undo.

Comment: PKDrawing no longer an opaque data object: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10148

Answer (score 2):

You can set the built-in selectors `undo:` and `redo:` to the first responder of the View Controller.

WWDC 19 has a demo has an example that does that in the storyboard itself. Here's the link for you:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented undo/redo... and wonder about the rest.